# Having trouble with school assignment c++ Time Calculator

Tags: c++

I know there should be something wrong with the calculations that finds how the days, hours, minutes, and seconds are found.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ();

{
int inputSeconds = 643600, days, remainingSeconds, hours, minutes, seconds;

days = inputSeconds / 86400;
remainingSeconds = inputSeconds % 86400;
hours = remainingSeconds / 3600;
remainingSeconds = inputSeconds % 3600;
minutes = remainingSeconds / 60;
seconds = inputSeconds % 60;
```

the if\else statements are also giving me trouble, however this might be due to the calculations.

```
  if (inputSeconds >= 86400)
{
  cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "<< days << " days, " << hours << " hours, " 
     << minutes << " minutes, and " << seconds << " seconds." << endl;
}
  else if (inputSeconds >= 3600)
{
  cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "<< hours << " hours, " 
       << minutes << " minutes, and " << seconds << " seconds." << endl;
}
  else if (inputSeconds >= 60)
{
  cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "<< seconds << " seconds." << endl;
}
  else
{
  cout << "Invalid entry. Enter a positive number for seconds. Try the program again." << 
       endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

When it is given 984561 seconds it gives the right output of

```
984561 seconds is 11 days, 9 hours, 29 minutes, and 21 seconds.
```

but when given 13 seconds the output is wrong and gives

```
Invalid entry. Enter a positive number for seconds. Try the program again.
```

I'm looking for

```
13 seconds is 13 seconds.
```

Comment: step through your code step-by-step with a debugger.

Comment: Please put together a [mcve].  Posting pieces of a chopped up program, where we don't know where those pieces are, is not going to be helpful.

Comment: You don't handle a case where `inputSeconds < 60`.

Comment: @OP Your program is still a jigsaw puzzle.  We have no idea where those lines of code you are posting are executed.  A [mcve] means that we can take your code, make absolutely *no* changes to it, compile it, and run it.

Comment: Yes, that output perfectly matches your code. Can you prove to me that I am wrong? How does execution proceed through your code when `inputSeconds` is 13?

Answer (score 0):

add another if else statement after

```
else if (inputSeconds >= 60)
   {
       cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "<< seconds << " seconds." << endl;
   }
```

so we can check numbers between 1-60 before negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int inputSeconds     = 13;
    int remainingSeconds = 0;

    int days         = inputSeconds / 86400;
    remainingSeconds = inputSeconds % 86400;

    int hours        = remainingSeconds / 3600;
    remainingSeconds = remainingSeconds % 3600;

    int minutes      = remainingSeconds / 60;
    int seconds      = remainingSeconds % 60;

    if ( inputSeconds >= 86400 ) {
        cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "
             << days << " days, "
             << hours << " hours, "
             << minutes << " minutes, and "
             << seconds << " seconds."
             << endl;
    } else if ( inputSeconds >= 3600 ) {
        cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "
             << hours << " hours, "
             << minutes << " minutes, and "
             << seconds << " seconds."
             << endl;
    } else if ( inputSeconds >= 60 ) {
        cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "
             << seconds << " seconds."
             << endl;
    } else if ( inputSeconds >= 0 ) {
        cout << inputSeconds << " seconds is "
             << seconds << " seconds." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Enter a positive number for seconds. Try the program again." << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```